# MYSQL: Add for each row one minute to a timestamp

Tags: mysql

in column "timestamp" (table: rand_numbers")  is in each row the same timestamp:
2016-09-26 00:00:13 
2016-09-26 00:00:13
2016-09-26 00:00:13
2016-09-26 00:00:13

i want to add in each row 1 minute, resulting in: 
2016-09-26 00:00:13
2016-09-26 00:01:13
2016-09-26 00:02:13
2016-09-26 00:03:13

this does not work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= 10 DO
        INSERT INTO rand_numbers (timestamp) 
         VALUES ('2016-09-26 00:00:13' + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5awU.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful diagnostic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use loop to insert

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE max INT DEFAULT 10;

    WHILE(count < max) DO
        INSERT INTO rand_numbers (timestamp) VALUES ('2016-09-26 00:00:13' + INTERVAL count MINUTE);
        SET count = count + 1;
    END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

To use run `call myproc();`

Comment: it does not work (you have an erroer in you syntax...); but i think only a few things have do be changed. what about setting "Delimeter$$"? And does "myproc()" needs a specific name like "myproc(example_name)"? please see my update above for how i applied your suggested query

Comment: where is the loop-statement in your query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
DECLARE @VALUE DATETIME

SET @intFlag = 1
SET @VALUE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

--print @VALUE
WHILE (@intFlag <=5)
BEGIN
    PRINT (DATEADD(minute,1,@VALUE));
    SET @VALUE = (DATEADD(minute,1,@VALUE));
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    CONTINUE;
END
```